# Is it possible to catch the exception generated by trying to connect to a bad url?

Tags: javascript, node.js, try-catch

using node http package it doesn't seem possible to catch the exception caused by opening a bad URL. This is a problem, because it kills my cluster, which I'd like to guarantee will live forever

Here's the code: (uses fibers.promise)

```
function openConnection(dest, port, contentType, method, throwErrorOnBadStatus)
{
  "use strict";
  assert.ok(dest, "generalUtilities.openConnection: dest is null");
  //dest = dest.replace('//','/');
  console.log('opening connection: ' + dest + " contentType: " + contentType);
  var prom = promise(),
    errProm = promise(),
    ar = [],
    urlParts = url.parse(dest),
    httpClient,
    req,
    got,
    res;
  //console.log('urlParts.port: ' + urlParts.port);
  if (port) {
    urlParts.port = port;
  } else if (!urlParts.port) {
    urlParts.port = 80;
  }
  if (contentType) {
    urlParts.accept = contentType;
  } else {
    urlParts.contentType = 'text/html';
  }
  if (!urlParts.method) {
    if (method) {
      urlParts.method = method;
    } else {
      urlParts.method = 'GET';
    }
  }
  try {
    httpClient = http.createClient(urlParts.port, urlParts.hostname);
    req = httpClient.request(urlParts.method, urlParts.path, urlParts);
  //console.log('req: ' + req);
  //if (req.connection) {
  //  req.connection.setTimeout(HTTP_REQUEST_TIMEOUT);
  //}
  //else {
  //  throw new Error ("No Connection Established!");
  //}
      req.end();
    req.on('response', prom);
    req.on('error', errProm);
    got = promise.waitAny(prom, errProm);
    if (got === errProm) {
      //assert.ifError(errProm.get(), HTTP_REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MSG + dest);
      throw new Error(HTTP_REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MSG + dest + ': ' + got.get());
    }
    res = prom.get();
    ar.res = res;
    ar.statusCode = res.statusCode;
    if (ar.statusCode >= 300 && throwErrorOnBadStatus) {
      assert.ifError("page not found!");
    }
    return ar;
  }
  catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

and here's how I tested it

```
var promise = require('fibers-promise');
var gu = require("../src/utils/generalutilities.js");

var brokenSite = 'http://foo.bar.com:94//foo.js';
promise.start(function () {
  try {
    gu.openConnection(brokenSite, null, null, "GET", true);
  }
  catch (err) {
    console.log('got: ' + err);
  }
});
```

When I run this code I get:

Error: getaddrinfo ENOENT. It is never caught in the try catch

Comment: Please use proper code formatting in the future. You just indent the whole code block by four spaces. Do not use `<pre><code>`.

Comment: So, what is the stack trace on the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works for me, when supplying an error handler for the request:

```
req.on('error', errorHandler);
```

I see that you also do that, but you set it after issuing

```
req.end();
```

Could you try issuing the `end()` after you attached the error handler?

As a side note, I *really* recommend [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request), as it handles issues like this with sensible defaults. It's really a breeze to work with.

**Edit:** Here is a simple example showing that attaching an error handler lets me handle `ENOENT`/`ENOTFOUND` errors:

```
var http = require('http');

var req = http.request({hostname: 'foo.example.com'}, function(err, res) {
    if(err) return console.error(err);
    console.log('got response!');
});

req.on('error', function(err) {
    console.error('error!', err);
});
```

Another piece of valuable information: I'm not sure how it fits in with fibers, but in general, you should *never* `throw` in nodejs asynchronous code. It rarely works the way you want. Instead, use the standard practice of passing any error as the first parameter to the next callback, and handle the error where it makes sense (usually, high up in the call chain where you can do something sensible with it).

Comment: Moving my end statement didn't work but I got it to work using request - I agree this library adds a lot to the basic http package!

Answer (score 0):

You can scrape the page for the error code.

Comment: It never even makes it to the page. It shoots me out with getaddrinfo ENOENT